# updating table values with correlated sub query

Tags: sql, oracle

[Database I am working from](https://i.stack.imgur.com/GtD9o.jpg)

I am trying to update the expertise_level in the expertise table by increasing the expertise_level associated with each employee_id in the expertise and faculty table that is equal to an instructor_id in the class_section table and has a year value equal to 2014 by adding 1 to every expertise_level value. Unless the expertise_level is not less than 8, in that case, nothing happens.

```
update expertise
    set expertise_level = (expertise_level +1)
    where (employee_id, expertise_level)  = 
        (select f.employee_id, expertise_level
        from class_section s join course c on (s.course_code = c.course_code) join expertise e on (c.course_code=e.course_code) join faculty f on(e.employee_id = f.employee_id)
        where year = '2014' AND expertise_level <8
        group by f.employee_id, expertise_level);
```

I am to use a correlated sub query to solve this problem, this is the query I have written and I am receiving an "INVALID RELATIONAL OPERATOR" error in Oracle and I am not sure why. Am I on the right track?

Answer (score 0):

Replace the operator '=' with 'in' in the where clause

```
...   
 where (employee_id, expertise_level) in
...
```

By using '=' You can only match with single value.